# RotationMode doen't work in a CAKeyframeAnimation (linear path)

Tags: ios, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I try to make my view rotate as long as it goes through the path (linear path) but it doesn't rotate.

This is my code:

```
 CAKeyframeAnimation *animKF = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animKF.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(400, 400)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(700, 100)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1000, 400)], nil];

animKF.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

animKF.duration = 6;

animKF.rotationMode =  kCAAnimationRotateAuto;

[imageView.layer addAnimation:animKF forKey:@"keyframe"];
```

But the imageView (the blue face in the picture) doesn't rotate along the path (the red line in the picture)

[image: Path]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`rotationMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAKeyframeAnimation/rotationMode):

> The effect of setting this property to a non-`nil` value when no path object is supplied is undefined.

In your code you are setting the `values`-property of your key frame animation but you need to set a [`path`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAKeyframeAnimation/path) instead.

---

You should create a CGPath from your values and set that as the path of your keyframe.

```
UIBezierPath *animationPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[animationPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[animationPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(400, 400)];
[animationPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(700, 100)];
[animationPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1000, 400)];

animKF.path = animationPath.CGPath;
```